# How to build my Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, psql

I have a problem that seems simple, but I can not solve it. If in my index I have as data :

```
 country | id | n1 | n2 | n3 | other
---------+----+----+----+----+-------
       1 |  1 |  0 |  2 |  0 |     1
       2 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  1 |     1
       2 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  1 |     2
       2 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  1 |     3
       2 |  3 |  1 |  1 |  1 |     1
       1 |  4 |  0 |  3 |  2 |     1
       1 |  4 |  0 |  3 |  2 |     2
```

How do I run the following query in Elasticsearch?

```
 select DISTINCT country, id, n1, n2, n3 from MyIndex;
 country | id | n1 | n2 | n3
---------+----+----+----+----
       2 |  3 |  1 |  1 |  1
       1 |  4 |  0 |  3 |  2
       1 |  1 |  0 |  2 |  0
       2 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  1
```

And especially :

```
select country, sum(n1), sum(n2), sum(n3) from (select DISTINCT country, id, n1, n2, n3 from MyIndex) as foo group by country;
 country | sum | sum | sum
---------+-----+-----+-----
       1 |   0 |   5 |   2
       2 |   2 |   1 |   2
```

Comment: no one has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `terms` and `sum` aggregations, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "countries": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_n1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "n1"
              }
            },
            "sum_n2": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "n2"
              }
            },
            "sum_n3": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "n3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: I just posted the result

Comment: You should not post an answer... anyway, I've updated my answer. Your question was ambiguous and was not clear that you also wanted by distinct ID.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Your new answer does not work either. I do not know how to send you the result because if I edit my question he does not want to save because there is too much code. To be clearer, I have the same data in postgres and in elasticsearch and I try to implement the queries I asked in my question.